# Should a conductor ever assume that they will be premiering a piece?

Tags: composers

Here's the story.  A conductor I know offered to look at my work.  He shared with me what he thought would work particularly well.  I found an old sketch and tailored to fit the strengths of his [community, non-auditioned] ensemble.

As it turns out, the piece came out very strong.  He was thrilled with it and has committed to playing it in about 12-18 months.  Since the piece is so good, I'd like to send it to other conductors I know.  If one if them were to like it and program it first, would that reflect poorly on my etiquette?

There was no financial discussion, and the piece was not commissioned.  We did not discuss whether it would be given with right of first performance, but the piece was completed with his ensemble in mind.

Comment: Does the conductor know, or have any reason to suspect, the piece has not previously been performed?

Comment: Since conductor 1 had musical input, it's now a shared baby. It's only polite, if you use the doctored manuscript to ask other conductors, but the 12-18 month wait is a good reason to give for not wanting to wait. You could always tell him that you'd like it re-re-arranged by others, too.

Comment: @Aaron yes, he knows that it was written with his ensemble in mind.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure I understand your comment

Comment: Since he knows it was written with his ensemble in mind, and he's agreed to play it — were I him, I would be pretty put out if I then found out you sent it to other conductors.

Comment: @Aaron so then he is right to assume that the first performance is his.  If you post as an answer I'd accept

Comment: From your question, I felt that the conductor worked with you to make a piece for his ensemble. So if another conductor changed it for a different ensemble... But if it's all your own work, you do what you want with it. He may be upset, but 12-18 mths is a long time and it may never get played for lots of reasons.

Comment: What you didn't state explicitly is whether the piece you intend to send to other conductors will contain the revisions of the first conductor. We don't know what that "tailoring" involved. Are going to send his revisions with only your name on it?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis the tailoring was mine alone.  We discussed general aspects of a piece that would be appealing for his orchestra, such as instrumentation, particular choirs to feature, etc.  He had no hand in the creation

Comment: @nuggethead: I think you should include your last comment in your question, as it is important information.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to him.   'Is that a definite that you'll be programming my piece next year?'   Because XYZ orchestra might be interested in doing it in the spring...